# Simple question on Hausdorff locally compact subspaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm reading through *Topology* by Dugundji and in chapter XI, theorem 6.5(2) the following argument is used in the proof (not a precise quote, I kept the essential parts):

> Let $A$ be a locally compact subset of a Hausdorff space $Y$. Each $a\in 
> A$ has a nbd $V(a)$ in $Y$ such that $\overline{V(a)}\cap A$ is compact, and therefore closed, in $Y$. [...]

I don't see how this is true. I attempted the following approach: Let $a\in A$, let $U$ be a relatively compact nbd of $a$ in $A$, then $U=V\cap A$ for some $V$ open in $Y$. But I'm not sure if $\overline{V}\cap A$ is compact and I can't think of another way of constructing a nbd that satisfies the required condition. I'm sure the explanation has to be direct and simple (sorry for that) but there might be something that I'm overlooking.

***Definitions***

A Hausdorff spaced is said to be **locally compact** if every point has a nbd with compact closure. A set is said to be **relatively compact** if it has compact closure. (note that a necessary condition for a space to be locally compact is that it be Hausdorff).

Comment: I share your doubts. We only know $\overline U\cap A$ is compact, and it may be smaller that $\overline V\cap A.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is wrong: Let $\mu$ be the smallest topology on the reals, which is finer than the usual topology and such that $Z := \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\} \}$ is closed.
(This is a well-known example for a T2 topology, which is not regular, see for instance Engelking, General topology 1.5.6.)
Then $A := Z \cup \{0\}$ is closed and discrete, hence locally compact.
Assume $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ such that $\overline{V} \cap A$ is compact. Then there exists $m \in \mathbb N$ such that
$(-\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{m}) \setminus Z \subset V$.
It is easy to see that $\overline{V} \cap A$ contains the closed and discrete subset $\{ \frac{1}{n}: n > m\}$. Contradiction.

BTW, it's not by chance that this space is not regular, since it is easy to see that the assumption holds, if $Y$ is regular.

Comment: Let me add for OP that the statement of 6.5.(2) in Dugundji's book is correct, it's just the proof that is flawed